# Batch size for Attention-based Multiple Instance Learning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, multiple-instances, attention-model

I'm new to Multiple Instance Learning, so studied by following the code of the paper (Ilse, M., Tomczak, J. M., & Welling, M. (2018). Attention-based Deep Multiple Instance Learning. arXiv preprint arXiv:1802.04712.).

In this paper, the batch_size was set as 1. In my understanding, this means the bag is processed one by one, and this is just online machine learning.
I would like to implement mini-batch learning. However, when I set the batch_size to a number that is greater than 1, the below error occurred.

```html
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(MnistBags(target_number=9,
                                                   mean_bag_length=10,
                                                   var_bag_length=2,
                                                   num_bag=100,
                                                   seed=1,
                                                   train=True),
                                         batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=True)

img, label = next(iter(train_loader))
----output-----
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [8, 1, 28, 28] at entry 0 and [9, 1, 28, 28] at entry 1
```

I guessed this error occurred because the number of instances in each bag differs and Pytorch cannot stack the tensor.

I would appreciate it if you could teach me how to solve this error.
Is it possible to perform mini-batch learning with MIL?

Thanks in advance.